# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Reshape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Im getting the error here:

```
def train_model(training_data, model=False):

     X = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data]).reshape(-1,len(training_data[0][0]),1)
     y = [i[1] for i in training_data]

     model = neural_network_model(input_size = len(X[0]))

     model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': y}, n_epoch=4, 
               snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True,
               run_id='snek_learning')
     return model
```

and here is the training_data array making:

```
for data in game_memory:
    if data[1] == 0: output = [1,0,0,0]
    elif data[1] == 1: output = [0,1,0,0]
    elif data[1] == 2: output = [0,0,1,0]
    elif data[1] == 1: output = [0,0,0,1]

    training_data.append([data[0], output])
```

I'm not sure if i'm reshaping it correctly, please help

EDIT:
creating `game_memory`:

```
    for _ in range(initial_games):
    score = 0
    game_memory = []
    prev_observation = []
    for _ in range(goal_steps):
        action = random.randrange(0,5)
        observation, reward, done = Next_Frame(action)
        if len(prev_observation) > 0 :
            game_memory.append([prev_observation, action])
        prev_observation = observation
        score=reward
        if done: break
```

where `observation` and `prev_observation` is always a list of 7 variables
EDIT 2:
10 iterations of `training_data` printed before passing to `train_model`:

```
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [0, 0, 0, 1]                 
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [1, 0, 0, 0]              
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [0, 0, 1, 0]                
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [1, 0, 0, 0]                      
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [0, 1, 0, 0]                     
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [0, 0, 0, 1]                  
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [0, 0, 1, 0]                 
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [0, 1, 0, 0]                
[False, False, False, True, False, True, False] [0, 0, 0, 1]               
[False, False, False, True, False, False, True] [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

EDIT NEXT:
the full error log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Szymon/Documents/snake_network.py", line 273, in <module>
    model = train_model(training_data)
  File "c:/Users/Szymon/Documents/snake_network.py", line 266, in train_model
    model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': y}, n_epoch=4, snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id='snek_learning')
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 216, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 339, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 818, in _train
    feed_batch)
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1104, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Can you explain what `data[0]` is? Does each `data[0]` in `game_memory` have the same size?

Comment: `training_data.append([data[0], output])`: that looks weird, if `output` is a 4-element list, and `data[0]` is (presumably) a single value. Have you tried printing out the shape (and possibly values) of `training_data` or other variables?

Comment: I suggest you print a small subset if the `training_data` getting to `train_model`, and post it here so it's easy to reproduce. Do not post in the comments, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51967731/edit) link.

Comment: data[0] is a 7-element list

Comment: I thought the error was on the first line, but it is not (at least with your example), please post the full stack as well.

Comment: @kabanus you mean the error log from terminal?

Comment: Yes, that has useful information, and should show exactly where the error is. Make a habit of posting these on SO.

Comment: Try converting `y`, either to a tuple or an array (`np.array(y)` or `tuple(y)`). If that works I will post that an answer.

Comment: @kabanus unfortunatelly it doesn't :/ still the same error